# Django takes care of `form` from `Field`

Tags: django

I am puzzled over the choices in models field in the following code:

```
class Block(models.Model
    STATUS = (
        (0,  'normal'),
        (-1, 'deleted'),
    )
    name = models.CharField("block name", max_length=100)
    desc = models.CharField("block description", max_length=100)
    admin = models.CharField("block admin", max_length=100)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Reference to `choices=STATUS`, I read from offical docs that Django utilize a form widget to handle the 2-tuples,
In the particular case, it send `0 -1` to database and issue `normal deleted` to template:

```
<select name="status">
  <option value=0>normal</option>
  <option value=-1>deleted</option>
</select>
```

It's amazing but confused.

How the amazing works?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. What do you mean by _"take care of form"_? Is everything working fine and you just want to understand how things work or is there something broken?

Comment: I want to know how things work @Selcuk

Comment: Now this is too broad to be answered here in a few paragraphs, but try reading the source code, especially https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L760 and https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L659

Comment: ty, I have not the privilege to upvote your comment, could you do a favor to copy it to answer. @Selcuk

Comment: I appreciate it, but that would be a link-only answer and would not fully answer your question. It is better to be left as a comment.